# NodeJS: How is cart not defined?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am working with an e-commerce application and I continue getting the following error:

`(node:71376) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ReferenceError: cart is not defined`

How is `cart` not defined here?

```
const express = require("express");
const cartsRepo = require("../repositories/carts");
const { Router } = require("express");
const productsRepo = require("../repositories/products");
const cartShowTemplate = require("../views/carts/show");

const router = express.Router();

// Receive a post request to add an item to a cart
router.post("/cart/products", async (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body.productId);
  // Figure out the cart!
  try {
    let cart;
    if (!req.session.cartId) {
      //   // we dont have a cart, we need to create one,
      //   // and store the cart id on the req.session.cartId property
      cart = await cartsRepo.create({ items: [] });
      req.session.cartId = cart.id;
    } else {
      //   // We have a cart! Lets get it from the repository
      cart = await cartsRepo.getOne(req.session.cartId);
    }

    
    const existingItem = cart.items.find(
      (item) => item.id === req.body.productId
    );
    if (existingItem) {
      // increment quantity and save cart
      existingItem.quantity++;
    } else {
      // add new product id to items array
      cart.items.push({ id: req.body.productId, quantity: 1 });
    }
    await cartsRepo.update(cart.id, {
      items: cart.items,
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }

  res.send("Product added to cart");
});

// Receive a GET request to show all items in cart
router.get("/cart", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    if (!req.session.cartId) {
      return res.redirect("/");
    }

    const cart = await cartsRepo.getOne(req.session.cartId);

    for (let item of cart.items) {
      const product = await productsRepo.getOne(item.id);

      item.product = product;
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }

  res.send(cartShowTemplate({ items: cart.items }));
});

// Receive a post request to delete an item from a cart

module.exports = router;
```

This is the `carts.js` file:

```
const Repository = require("./repository");

class CartsRepository extends Repository {}

module.exports = new CartsRepository("carts.json");
```

That JSON file has:

```
[
  {
    "items": [],
    "id": "d068d19a"
  },
  {
    "items": [],
    "id": "7fb21ae7"
  },
  {
    "items": [],
    "id": "fa6af1d1"
  },
  {
    "items": [],
    "id": "e64012d9"
  },
  {
    "items": [],
    "id": "77ebb5ed"
  },
  {
    "items": [],
    "id": "b68686f0"
  },
  {
    "items": [],
    "id": "977eded8"
  },
  {
    "items": [],
    "id": "5601d00b"
  },
  {
    "items": [],
    "id": "d10c8afd"
  },
  {
    "items": [],
    "id": "82e18133"
  },
  {
    "items": [
      {
        "id": "",
        "quantity": 5
      }
    ],
    "id": "05b757b9"
  }
]
```

I did try putting the `res.send(cartShowTemplate({ items: cart.items }));` inside the `try/catch` like so:

```
// Receive a GET request to show all items in cart
router.get("/cart", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    if (!req.session.cartId) {
      return res.redirect("/");
    }

    const cart = await cartsRepo.getOne(req.session.cartId);

    for (let item of cart.items) {
      const product = await productsRepo.getOne(item.id);

      item.product = product;
    }
    res.send(cartShowTemplate({ items: cart.items }));
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
});
```

and then I got this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined
```

which is in reference to what I have in `views/show.js`:

```
const layout = require("../layout");

module.exports = ({ items }) => {
  const renderedItems = items
    .map((item) => {
      return `
      <div>${item.product.title} - ${item.product.price}</div>
    `;
    })
    .join("");

  return layout({
    content: `
        <h1>Cart</h1>
        ${renderedItems}
      `,
  });
};
```

I recently attempted this refactor:

```
router.get("/cart", async (req, res) => {
  if (!req.session.cartId) {
    return res.redirect("/");
  }

  const cart = await cartsRepo.getOne(req.session.cartId);

  const items = await Promise.all(
    cart.items.map(async (item) => ({
      ...item,
      product: await productsRepo.getOne(item.id),
    }))
  );

  res.send(cartShowTemplate({ items }));
});
```

but when I click on the cart link to take me to the cart menu, I still get this error:

```
(node:71588) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined
```

Answer (score 1):

In your `router.get("/cart"...` route handler you define `cart` as a `const` inside the `try` block. `const` variables are block scoped so you it only exists inside the block. You try to use it outside the block with:

`res.send(cartShowTemplate({ items: cart.items }));`

You'll need to declare the variable outside the try block, or move the `res.send` inside the block if you want to use a const here.

Here's a minimal example that demonstrates the issue:

```js
try {
  const cart = "some value"
} catch (error) {
  console.log(error);
}

console.log(typeof cart)
```

Comment: @Daniel, seems like there are multiple separate issues now that this question is serving.

Comment: Also, check my answer which addresses both the issues you've presented.

Comment: @dillon, I tried your solution and I am still getting `Cannot read property 'title' of undefined`

Comment: You used the `Promise.all` ? If so, I would suggest logging the result of `await productsRepo.getOne(item.id)` because it might not be returning what you want..

Comment: @dillon, I get `product is not defined`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220686/discussion-between-dillon-and-daniel).

Answer (score 0):

As Mark Meyer pointed out, using `const` scopes the variable to the containing block.

You can perform `res.send()` inside the try block where cart is in scope like so:

```js
// ...

// Receive a GET request to show all items in cart
router.get("/cart", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    if (!req.session.cartId) {
      return res.redirect("/");
    }

    const cart = await cartsRepo.getOne(req.session.cartId);
    
    for (let item of cart.items) {
      const product = await productsRepo.getOne(item.id);

      item.product = product;
    }

    res.send(cartShowTemplate({ items: cart.items }));
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
});

// ...
```

Additionally, I'd suggest using `Promise.all` to populate the product for each item. This will kick the product requests off concurrently and speed up the requests:

```js
    // ... 

    const cart = await cartsRepo.getOne(req.session.cartId);

    const items = await Promise.all(cart.items.map(async item => ({
        ...item,
        product: await productsRepo.getOne(item.id),
    })))

    res.send(cartShowTemplate({ items }));

    // ...
```

### EDIT... addressing second issue of item.product.title being undefined.

The issue here is that you're trying to mutate `item` inside a `for in` loop, however, the `for in` loop is creating a new `item` object inside the loop, so you're not mutating the external array. Here is an example which shows the issue...

```js
let items = [{test:1},{test:2}];
for (let item in items) {
    item.product = `product${item.test}`
}
console.log(items);
```

Answer (score 0):

The answers above were correct in regards to the `try/catch` block, but I continued getting errors not because of the programming logic but because of two things.

Inside of `layout.js` I was missing the `/cart` on the `href`:

```
 <div class="navbar-item">
  <a href="/cart"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i> Cart</a>
 </div>
```

and inside of `products/index.js` I was missing the `product.id` inside of `value=""`

```
<input hidden value="${product.id}" name="productId" />
```